# SQL UNION with renamed columns

Tags: sql, union-all

I tried to make a new table,c, renaming user1 to user2, user2 to user 1 and UNION ALL the original table.

```
WITH c AS 
(
    SELECT 
        user1 AS user2, user2 AS user1, msg_count 
    FROM f
) 
SELECT * 
FROM c 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user1, user2, msg_count 
 FROM f)
```

This is f, the original table:

| id | date | user1 | user2 | msg_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-08-02 | kpena | scottmartin | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-08-02 | misty19 | srogers | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-08-02 | jerome75 | craig23 | 3 |

The question is: why am I not getting a rename-columned table to UNION? My query returned a UNION of two identical original tables

The output is this:

| id | user2 | user1 | msg_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpena | scottmartin | 2 |
| 2 | misty19 | srogers | 2 |
| 3 | jerome75 | craig23 | 3 |
| 4 | kpena | scottmartin | 2 |
| 5 | misty19 | srogers | 2 |
| 6 | jerome75 | craig23 | 3 |

which is not what I expected, I was expecting this instead:

| id | user2 | user1 | msg_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpena | scottmartin | 2 |
| 2 | misty19 | srogers | 2 |
| 3 | jerome75 | craig23 | 3 |
| 4 | scottmartin | kpena | 2 |
| 5 | srogers | misty19 | 2 |
| 6 | craig23 | jerome75 | 3 |

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the issue, consider the output of just selecting from your CTE - you have renamed the columns, but the order (left to right) remains unchanged, so now think about `select *`...

Your desired results rely on you selecting the correct columns, not their order:

```
with c as (select user1 as user2, user2 as user1, msg_count from f) 
select user1, user2, msg_count
from c 
union all (select user1, user2, msg_count from f);
```

Comment: Hey Stu, thanks so much! This has puzzled me for a long time and yes the select * is doing something wrong here

Comment: Hopefully a lesson that reinforces the good practice of always naming selected columns :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a CTE

You only need to switch the columns around for user1 and two:

```
(SELECT user1 AS user2, user2 AS user1, msg_count FROM f)
UNION ALL (SELECT user2, user1, msg_count FROM f)
```

Your query adds the same result twice, but as I already wrote the second query must have the user1 and user2 reversed, to get your result

Comment: Thanks! :)
My question is why I wasn't getting the expected result of a rename-columned table to UNION?

Comment: @user13206017 you can see in my query that is wswitched the user coluns to get your wanted result, and don't use CTE s for simple queries